# How do I add a row to a tibble in R?

Tags: r, tibble

I want my `tibble` to have two columns and two rows, but I'm not sure as to how to add another row. For some reason, it's only displaying the first row and not the second.

```
averages_by_host <- tibble(is_superhost = 0:1, average_prices = 124.699:127.5805) 
view(averages_by_host)
```

Running the code will show the tibble as:

[image]

However, I want it to look like this instead

[image]

Comment: The `:` is incrementing by 1, resulting in `124.699:127.5805#
[1] 124.699 125.699 126.699` -> in a length difference between 0:1 you need `tibble(is_superhost = 0:1, average_prices = c(124.699,127.5805))`

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much!